# Can I become a secondary lessee with no credit history?

Tags: united-states, real-estate-leasing, connecticut

I want to rent an apartment with my girlfriend.  At the moment I don't have any credit or proof of income, but I am finally earning enough through freelancing to afford the rent.  I have an emergency fund in a savings account that I can use to keep me afloat if needed.

My girlfriend has a credit history and so should not have a problem getting the lease.  Is there any way I can get on the lease as well, perhaps as a secondary while she is the primary?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Some landlords require all residents to be on the lease, but as JoeTaxpayer's question indicates, a lot depends on the local laws in your area.

Comment: I am from the US, specifically Connecticut.

Comment: Any idea anyone?

Comment: You might want to talk to people in your area who share apartments with others, and ask them what the landlord made them do as far as signing the lease.  If it's normal practice where you live for landlords to require all residents to be on the lease, you won't have a choice.  The landlord may not care as much about your income if your girlfriend can qualify on her own, but it's hard to know and could depend on the individual landlord.

Comment: Do you want to be on the lease because you think it will help your credit score? Most landlords don't report to the credit agencies. What might be better is to try to get one or more of the utilities in your name.